# Random selection of testimonials

Tags: php

$message doesn't seem to be displaying anything.

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$files = glob("testimonials/*.txt");
$filename = $files[rand(0, count($files)-1)];
$lines = file($filename);
$author = array_shift($lines);
$message = explode("", $lines);
?>

<h1>Testimonial</h1>
<p><b>Author:</b> <?php echo $author; ?></p>
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

In my testimonials folder, I have text files with author name one the first line, then the message on the lines directly under that.

What am I missing here to make this work correctly?

Comment: your shifting/removing the first line, you say thats the authors name, is the rest of the `$message` on second line without a line break?, you could use `$lines[0]` for author name and then `implode($lines)` into a string the use str_replace() to remove the author from the message

Comment: Authors name is on line 1 and the rest of the message is on second line; no line break, no extra space. Let me try out your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php
$files = glob("testimonials/*.txt");
                 //mt_rand is more random
$filename = $files[mt_rand(0, count($files)-1)];

$lines = file($filename);
//Get authors name
$author=$lines[0];
/*Glue the whole $lines array into a string & remove the author,
  so whats left is just the message*/
$message=str_replace($author,'',implode(' ',$lines));
?>

<h1>Testimonial</h1>
<p><b>Author:</b> <?php echo $author; ?></p>
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use, but I don't have many testimonials yet!

```
function getTestimonial(){
// testimonials for Stay-in-Touch.ca    
$q = array ();
$q[] = " I was very impressed by your gadget - Grandma used it to show me
            loads of new photos of her latest batch of great-grandchildren - it's
            just the thing for her.<br>Philip Exeter, UK ";
$q[] = "The best time for the tablet was when my mom was in the hospital for three weeks before 
    and after her procedure. J went all around my mom&#39;s house, taking pictures of all her plants with
    her iPhone (many many plants, and my mom loves them all) and uploading them to the tablet. My mom 
    would just lay in her bed and see how her plants were doing (comments like &#39;oh, it&#39;s flowering 
    this year!&#39;), and it would calm her down. <br> M Toronto";
$q[] = "Mum really likes the pictures of the new babiy in the family. She can see how fast he is growing.<br> J Montreal";
$thisOne = rand(0,count($q)-1);
return $q[$thisOne];
```

}